# how to get data in code behind from api

Tags: asp.net, api

How to get country name from api codebehind file so i can use it to display in gridview?

```
foreach (var i in data)
string country = "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=xx.xx.xx.xx"
country=country+"i.ip";
i.Country = country;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that contains keys from http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp as String property. The minimum looks like this:

```
   public class GeoPlugin
    {
        public String geoplugin_countryName { get; set; }
    }
```

Perform a HttpWebRequest and deserialize the JSON response into the class you created and access the country property:

```
String url = String.Format("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip={0}", "173.194.112.31");
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
   JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   var result = jss.Deserialize<GeoPlugin>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
   i.Country = result.geoplugin_countryName;
}
```

To use `JavaScriptSerializer` you need to reference `System.Web.Extensions` (Version 4.0 ) and not use the .net 4.0 Client Profile.

Comment: @ citronas - how to do like this with Google API?

Comment: http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip .. this api is not reliable .... any idea how to do with     >>>   http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=12.215.42.19  ... to get only country name

Comment: Just change the properties of the GeoPlugin classes to match the names of the JSON response you provided